# Advantages of using Azure Service Bus Queues with WCF

Tags: wcf, azure, service, message-queue

What are the advantages of using Service bus queue with WCF? Why can't we use QueueClient to access the queue rather than consuming it with WCF services?

Answer (score 0):

I was using message queue with WCF in one of my application rather than use the paint queue client (I'm using RabbitMQ in local). Some reasons from my team's perspective

1, We have been using WCF over net.tcp for our application. In order to improve the performance and scalability we decided to use RabbitMQ. With WCF wrapped we don't need to update the whole system code, just change the WCF transport extension and configuration.

2, We can leverage WCF channel stack mode, switch security settings, message encoding, etc. We need to build our own if use plaint queue client.

3, We can leverage the message exchange patterns WCF provides.

4, It's very easy to extend and customize WCF so that we can add/replace modules we need.

Basically we want to use WCF architecture ranter than design and implement by ourselves.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Shaun! One more question, setting communication two way is very easy through RabbitMQ clients. But i guess if you wrap it in WCF, you will have to use duplex feature. And how WCF with rabbitMQ is more scalable and performant then net.tcp?

Comment: I implemented, I called strict duplex in my application, which means it's 1:1 communication. I also implemented wildcard duplex, which means service instance can send callback to any clients which implements the callback contract.

Comment: You did not answer the second question "And how WCF with rabbitMQ is more scalable and performant then net.tcp"